# libva error when trying to make an app in electron

Tags: drivers, graphics, chromium, electron

I'm trying to make a desktop app using Electron, but I'm getting this error repeatedly when trying to run electron. I've searched it online and got to know that it is because of chromium and it is something related to gpu and stuff, I don't get those things. This is the error:

```
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
```

The only this I have in my `main.js` is `console.log("Hello World")` (Yes, I've changed the main file to `main.js` in `package.json`)

**Specs**:
Software: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (64-bit)
Processor: Intel® Core™ i3-7020U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4
Graphics: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2F)
Windowing System: Wayland (are this and the next one necessary?)
GNOME: 42.9

Comment: Seems this problems comes with Electron 26.

Comment: Yeah, I've figured it out. Seems like we can't do anything about it.